# How to remove background color in hover and change it to underline but with space between text and line in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, underline

Thank you for reading and answering my question. What I would like to do is have my links underlined once it is hovered. Without background color and with space between text. Sort of something like this using bootstrap. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJpQI.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Internship Exercise 1</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body><!--Navbar start-->
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-default navbar-static-top navpadding" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="90%"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navmargin" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#" class="underline">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With CSS here that have a temporary underline for active. How can I do this for hover? Looking forward to your answer. Thanks!

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
}
.underline {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well that's why :hover exists :)

HTML:

```
<body><!--Navbar start-->
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-default navbar-static-top navpadding" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Male_mallard_duck_2.jpg" alt="logo" height="100%"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navmargin" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar{
  background:pink!important;
  padding:10px;
}
.navbar li *:hover{
  color:red!important;
}
.navbar li:hover{
  border-bottom:3px solid white;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dp17vjus/